# remove element from jsonarray

Tags: arrays

My JSONArray is

```
[
{"name":"Test_1","address":"test1"},
{"name":"Test_2","address":"test2"},
{...},
...]
```

I want to remove the first element i.e. the JSONArray should be like this after removing first element

```
[
{"name":"Test_2","address":"test2"},
{...},
...]
```

How can I achieve that in java? Your help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data inside a org.json.simple.JSONArray named myJsonArray, you can simply remove it with the remove method:

```
myJsonArray.remove(0);
```

You can then retrieve the string representation with the method toJSONString() from the JSONObject which your jsonArray is attached to.